# Why am I getting a "fetch out of sequence" error upon having Java program run insert statement?

Tags: java, sql, sql-update

My java program currently runs select statement queries to obtain information. It then takes that info and inserts it into an update statement before the code executes it. Here's what the code looks like:

```
//UPDATE
    q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("update"); //update query found in app properties file
    q.setParameter("ItemId", s);
    q.setParameter("Number", str);
    System.out.println("Update Statement for P/F was ran"); 
    q.executeUpdate();
```

The select statement queries I mentioned are similar in format to the UPDATE code above.

Now when this update code is ran, the query is executed successfully. I can check the DB and see that the statement updated the necessary values successfully! However, the java program itself outputs "fetch out of sequence" to the console and stops the rest of the queries in the program from running, like so:

```
2022-06-13 16:56:00.878 ERROR 33060 --- [nio-8004-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exc
eption [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause

oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
```

And there's more traces of the error below the above output but I think this is the most relevant bit of the outputted error.

I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out what's causing this issue and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This case maybe cause by When you are traversing the result of select SQL, the SQL of update data is triggered, and executeUpdate will automatically submit, so please stop the automatic submission of executeUpdate, and execute the submission after the traversal is over. I hope my idea can help you, thank you.